# STM32 Virtual COM Port appears as Device in DFU Mode on Windows 10

Tags: embedded, stm32, stm32f4

So, my knowladge in embedded development is quite bad and now I am trying to receive some data from PC inside my MCu `STM32F429IGT6` which is on WaveShare Core4X9I dev-board and send it back via USB Virtual COM Port.

I realized how to set up connection from MCu part and I even see connected device from Windows 10 Device Manager but... it appears as STM Device in `DFU Mode`

I have tryed already to install drivers from ST for such things but they are useless and official documentation says that they are not needed for Windows 10.

I have been following tutorials where guys just clicked several times inside Cube MX, generated code and VCP worked out of the box.

The question is what am I doing wrong? I don`t even know what information you might ask for thats why I created GitHub repo: https://github.com/dessy4oko/stm32f429-vcp-appears-as-dfu

And this is events from Device Manager of Windows 10 (translation from ru lang):

1. Device USB\VID_0483&PID_DF11\305233703237 is running. `code 410`
2. Device USB\VID_0483&PID_DF11\305233703237 is configured. `code 400`
3. Device USB\VID_0483&PID_DF11\305233703237 have not been moved due to partial or ambiguous matching. `code 442`
4. Device USB\VID_0483&PID_DF11\305233703237 requires further installation. `code 430`

Thank you for any information about my mistakes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

STM32 starts in DFU mode if BOOT-pins are pulled accordingly:
[image: Boot modes]
"System memory" means embedded bootloader, DFU in this case. You need "Main Flash" to run your app.

Check jumpers and switches on your board. Refer also to the [AN2606](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/cd00167594-stm32-microcontroller-system-memory-boot-mode-stmicroelectronics.pdf) app note for complete information.

Comment: Oh, such a simple mistake... I thought that this jumper switches between program locations. Okay, I see now, thank you so much! Closed.